# Why are these conditions necessary?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm asked the following question:

> Let $\alpha:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular, injective curve with everywhere non-zero curvature. Assume that $M$, the image of 
>   $$r:I\times\mathbb{R}_+, r(t,v)=\alpha(t)+v\alpha'(t)$$
>   is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $r$ is a regular parametrisation. Compute $T_pM$ for $p\in M$

When I compute $T_pM$ I find:

$$r_t=\alpha'+v\alpha''$$
$$r_v=\alpha'$$
Hence 
$$T_pM=\text{span}\{\alpha'+v\alpha'',\alpha'\}=\text{span}\{\alpha'',\alpha'\}$$
Now since $r$ is a regular parametrisation of $M$, we know that these vectors must be linearly independent, and thus that in particular $\alpha'\not=0$ so $\alpha$ must be regular.

I don't see why we need $\alpha$ to be injective for this.

Also, since $\kappa\mathbf{N}=\frac{1}{|\alpha'|}\alpha''$ there is no way the curvature is zero, since $\kappa=0\implies \alpha''=0$, but that's not possible, again because $r$ is a regular parametrisation.

I feel like this question maybe should have been

> Let $\alpha:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular, injective curve with everywhere non-zero curvature. **Proof** that $M$, the image of 
>   $$r:I\times\mathbb{R}_+, r(t,v)=\alpha(t)+v\alpha'(t)$$
>   is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $r$ is a regular parametrisation. Compute $T_pM$ for $p\in M$

Am I correct in that the fact that $r$ is a regular parametrisation implies the conditions imposed on $\alpha$ in the first sentence, or am I overlooking something here? Because I think you need all three of those conditions to conclude that $M$ is a surface and $r$ a reg param.

Thanks.

Comment: Proof is a noun; Prove is a verb.

Comment: I see that $M$ is the _image_ of $r$. If the surface self-intersects, $T_pM$ is not defined. This is probably why injectivity was required.

Comment: @MiceElf Yes I know. But this again shows thats the conditions on $/alpha$ are only needed if you want to prove at $M$ is a surface. If you assume it is, then you don't need them anymore right?

Comment: I don't know the definitions the author of the text uses, but generally, a regular parametrization allows for self intersections.